# How to change drupal views filter from string to in opreator

Tags: views, 8

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
*/
function ***_views_data_alter(array &$data) {
  $data['content_moderation_state_field_data']['moderation_state']['filter']['id'] = 'content_moderation_state_select';
}


/**
 *
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("content_moderation_state_select")
 */
class ModerationStateFilter extends InOperator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function init(ViewExecutable $view, DisplayPluginBase $display, array &$options = NULL) {
    parent::init($view, $display, $options);
    $this->definition['options callback'] = array($this, 'generateOptions');
  }

  /**
   * Helper function that generates the options.
   * @return array
   */
  public function generateOptions() {
    $workflow = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('workflow')->load('editorial');
    $destinations = $workflow->getStates();
    $options = [];
    foreach ($destinations as $item){
      $options[$item->id()] = $this->t($item->label());
    }
    return $options;
  }
}
```

This works fine on config views,but can't save views conrrect.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are aware that the core team is working on a patch for this in this issue? https://www.drupal.org/node/2862041 Perhaps that will get you further?

Comment: @Neograph734 Thank you very much,that is what i need.I miss the schema file for filter value.

Answer (score 0):

Add filter value schema file in your module config/schema dir works fine.
***.views.schema.yml

```
# Schema for the views filter value.
views.filter.content_moderation_state_select:
  type: views.filter.in_operator
  label: 'Moderation state'

views.filter_value.content_moderation_state_select:
  type: views.filter_value.in_operator
```